# Disable ListView Item's listeners

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, swipe

I have a ListView with different types of rows. The row may contain text, image, video or something else. If I click on ImageView (inside the row) I will go to another activity to show the image in full screen, If I click on Video (inside the row) I will go to another activity to play he video.

I have implemented right to left swipe listener on my ListView. If I start the ListView swipe from an empty space in ListView, the swipe works (first and second row in below image). However if I start the ListView swipe from the ListView row's item, then the swipe doesn't work (third and fourth row in below image). If I remove the click events from ImageView and Video then the swipe works even if I start the swipe from the ListView row's item i.e. in this case the swipe works on whole ListView, no matter on which row I do the swipe.

[image]

How can I get rid on this problem? I think this can be achieved if I disable all the click events on the all the items inside ListView. How can do so? Is there any other way?

I want both swipe on ListView and click on ListView's item.

Comment: Please help me out guys.

Answer (score 0):

**Trick way**, you can call item of listview's onTouchListener, when the Image or Video was clicked. Simply call imageview's onTouch method.

```
ImageView image; // your image view, and asuume the it is initialized.

row.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                     
        image.onTouchEvent(event);
        break;                     
    }

    return false;
}
```

});

**OR**, It seems that, your image or video has it's own onTouchListener. The problem is, they consume the event and do not send them to it's parent view. So, do not return **"true"**, and the event will be sent to it's parent.

Comment: My ImageView or video doesn't have onTouchListener but onClickListener.

Comment: please help me out. My ImageVewi or VideoView doesn't have onTouchListener but onClickListener instead.